# How to remove a photo shared from iPhone via Skype?

Tags: privacy, photo-sharing, skype-for-web

I shared a picture taken with my iPhone with a friend. To my confusion, I've discovered that she received not a picture, as I expected, but a link to the image uploaded to Skype website. The image contains private information which I'm very unwilling to share online in any way.

Is that picture accessible to anyone having a Skype account or only to the signed in user I've shared the image with? How might I remove it from the website?

Comment: : ) I'd better shared some adult content

Comment: Generally you're right, but the problem is Skype for iPhone not share pictures as files, but upload them to the website and drops only a link to a recipient.

Comment: That's part of the issue. I have no convenience in security of Skype service, so the less my information is exposed to the outer world is better. When Skype generates a link and made the photo available over it without any prompt, that's scares me a little bit. However, it looks like only the message recipient after sign in could see an image using a link.

Comment: Thank you @pnuts. Hope so:) Also thanks for the edit, my grammar is terrible in the midnight.

Comment: Spent 2 hours chatting with Skype support without any visible result. That company is hopeless.